# Django all possible Q() arguments?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am reading Django documentation, particularly about Q() class.
It has several sections about it, like: [Q() objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) and [Complex lookups with Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) 
There, authors mention arguments that can be passed to Q(), like

```
Q(question__startswith='What')
```

I know that there are other arguments possible, like

```
Q(name__icontains='What')
```

This brings me to the conclusion, that a complete list of all available args must exist somewhere, unfortunately, despite that, searching through official documentation or googling lead to nothing

If someone can explain me, what should I do in this situation, it will be much appreciated

*UPD
@FamousJameous comment pointed me to the right place, idk if this thread should be kept for dumbs like I am or deleted for uselessness.

Comment: Are you looking for the [field lookups list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups)?

Comment: Looks like I'm either dumb or read too much today, yes, that is what I want, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation said:

> A Q() object, like an F object, encapsulates a SQL expression in a
>   Python object that can be used in database-related operations

so the Q objects can receive all the fields of a model field or annotated column. so if you define a model like:

```
class Home(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

You can use:

```
Home.objects.filter(Q(address="user address"))
```

so you can use any field from your model with the Q objects. you can also use the all built-in [fields lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) and your [custom-lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-lookups/) in your queries.